# iheart sbt-play-swagger playJava := true flag not found

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to make the https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger plugin to work with my Play 2.8 Java project.
Trying the endpoint

> http://127.0.0.1:9000/docs/swagger-ui/*file

I'm seeing

> Action Not Found

If I try smth like `http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/swagger.json`

I keep seeing error on swagger ui:

```
Fetch errorNot Found /swagger.json
```

My build.sbt contains
`lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayMinimalJava, SwaggerPlugin)`
and `swaggerDomainNameSpaces := Seq("models.domain")`

My plugins.sbt contains:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.iheart" % "sbt-play-swagger" % "0.10.2-PLAY2.8")
```

I'm pretty sure I followed all the steps correctly.
I think the problem is that I found that for Java project an additional step is required, and I cannot enable that flag: `playJava := true`
The error is:

> build.sbt:31: error: not found: value playJava
> playJava := true
> ^
> [error] Type error in expression

How can I solve this?

Comment: have you generated the swagger file? can you view it in the target directory?

Comment: @A-Developer-Has-No-Name No, it's not generated

Comment: thats the problem then , the way the plugin works is it generates a swagger.json and loads it. if it doesnt exist you will get a 404. try running the sbt task 'swagger'

Comment: @A-Developer-Has-No-Name yes, I know that's the problem, and I think the plugin is supposed to solve it... I ran what you said, it doesn't, shows smth like `Expected ';'
[error] Not a valid command: task (similar: tasks, last, alias)`

Comment: That means the plugin is not loaded , I recommend, updating your sbt project

Comment: @A-Developer-Has-No-Name I did that several times

Comment: what happens when you type in 'plugins' in the sbt console, do you see the plugin listed? It also seems like playMinimalJava is not loaded